# Is there any way to use lower camel case style when pass object from .NET to JavaScript in CefSharp?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, cefsharp

Lower camel case style is convention in JavaScript. Default is not lower camel case style when I pass object from .NET to JavaScript in CefSharp.

```
public void GetTestDataWithCallback(IJavascriptCallback callback)
{
    callback.ExecuteAsync(new TestData
                          {
                              Id = 1,
                              Name = "Johnny",
                              Test = new TestData
                                     {
                                         Id = 2,
                                         Name = "Mary"
                                     }
                          });
}
```

The above code will receive in JavaScript:

`{"Id":1,"Name":"Johnny","Test":{"Id":2,"Name":"Mary","Test":null}}`

Is there any way to use lower camel case style?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control naming via the JavascriptObjectRepository.NameConverter

The code look something like the following.

```cs
chromiumWebBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.NameConverter = new CamelCaseJavascriptNameConverter();
```

Make sure to set the property shortly after the ChromiumWebBrowser instance is created.

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you.